# Unable to install Program

Tags: software-installation, gnu

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and since last Friday I am trying to install GNU Image Manipulation Program. After several attempts, it now shows the error message below (also see the screenshot):

> Unable to install "GNU Image Manipulation Program":
>   snap "gimp" has "install-snap" change in progress

[image: Error massage]

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: note, that the accepted answer in that Q is another option to do what OP wanted, but does not fix the initial problem, (see the answer with most upvotes) ...

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. :) I'll try and let you know the progress.